# is it possible to use IN in IF?

Tags: mysql, plsql

I would like to ask is it possible to use IN in IF conditions in MySQL like this:

```
IF (leave_type IN('M', 'X', 'B') THEN
```

Comment: All you have to do is try it by yourself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could be answered by simple experiment

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CASE WHEN` statement like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN leave_type IN('M', 'X', 'B') 
    THEN 'True'
    ELSE 'False'
END
```

**Update**:

You can also do an `IF` like this:

```
IF(leave_type IN ('M','X','B'),'True','False')
```

Reference:

- [13.6.5.1 CASE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Comment: I can't see the need for a `CASE` here. A simple `IF` is sufficient: `IF(leave_type IN ('M','X','B'),'This','That')`

Comment: @SylvainLeroux : Sure you can do a `IF` in that matter. I updated the answer. I just thought it is nice with a `CASE WHEN`

Comment: As the OP _needs_ are not very clear, it is hard to tell for sure.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux : I agree